# PHP oop echo session username?

Tags: php, session, pdo

I'm pretty clueless on how to retrieve or echo a username from the database,

i have referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592081/php-oop-passing-session-key-between-classes)

and more similar questions like this, however i still don't understand how to echo out the current user username.

everything works fine, i can login and logout

just cant get find a way to echo current username

here is the code

User.php

```
public function get_user_sess()
{
    try{

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=':username'");
        $query->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
        $userRow = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['username'];

    }

    catch(PDOExeception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function login($username, $password)
{
    try{
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=:username OR user_pass=:password LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password ));
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            if(password_verify($password,$userRow['user_pass']))
            {
                $_SESSION['login'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                return true;

            }

            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    catch(PDOExeception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Profile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);
require_once 'User.php';

$user = new User();
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
   $user->logout();
   $user->redirect('login');
}


require_once 'layouts/header.php';
?>
<h1>Welcome 
<?php 

$user = new User();
echo $user->get_user_sess();
?>
</h1>

<ul>
    <li><a href="profile.php?q=logout">LOGOUT</a></li>
</ul>

<?php require_once ('layouts/footer.php');?>
```

Login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);
require 'Db.php';
require 'User.php';



if(isset($_POST['btn_login'])){


    $username = $_POST['txt_username'];
    $password = $_POST['txt_pass'];


    $guest = new User();
    if($username == "")
    {
        echo "Enter username please";

    }

    if($password == "")
    {
        echo "Enter password please";
    }



    if($guest->login($username, $password)){
        $guest->redirect('profile');      
    }


    else{
        echo "Invalid Entry";
    }





}

require_once 'layouts/header.php';

?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Sign In</h1>


        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="txt_username" class="form-control" required/>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="txt_pass" class="form-control" required/>
            </div>


         <button type="submit" name="btn_login" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put session_start() on top of your user.php

Comment: @MuhammadUsman i dont think its a session thing i think. here is the error i got
`A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eli14/User.php on line 2`

Comment: $query->execute(array(':username'=>$username)); What about $username variable it is out of scope of function -- Is it global?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman its not global, what the correct format for retrieving a username ?thanks

Comment: Please check here http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/php-login-and-registration-script-with.html

Comment: your query is failing on the named placeholder

Comment: @Fred-ii- i dont understand

Comment: `WHERE user_name=':username'` along with http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php will throw you a syntax error and is 99% of the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In user.php file just set the session variable.
For example in your function:

```
  $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userrow['username'];
```

Here do not return anything. Just set the session variable.

Now in any page where you want the username to be displayed 
Write

```
 session_start ();
 echo $_SESSION['user_session'];
```

Hope it clears your problem.
Also in your PDO statement change

```
user_name=':username' // in select statement
```

To

```
user_name=:username   // without inverted commas
```

Here no need of ':username' writing with inverted commas.
Also no need of FETCH_ASSOC as you are getting only one row. So use fetch()  PDO function.
More updates:

See first login the user in your application. In the login script itself set the username session variable. Then

1. In the profile page access the session value by calling

   ```
    session_start ();
     echo $_SESSION['user_session'];
   ```

   If you have doubt please update your login script file I will show you.

Hope you understand.

Third update:

1. See in your login function you have already set the session variable

   ```
   $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
   ```

   Therefore you are always getting the user I'd value from the session variable.
2. So in the login function itself set

   ```
   $_SESSION['username'] = $userRow['username'];
   ```

   And then call this variable in the profile page. There no need to call the get_user_sess() function. Just start the session and get the variable.

Also your login script must sanitize user input values.

Comment: you also made an syntax error with `row ['username']` which will throw an undefined constant error.

Comment: yeah it still didnt work, i get no errors which is good, but no username echos

Comment: @CoderSam 

user_name=:username // in select statement 

change it to what ?

Comment: Remove inverted commas.

Comment: it still does not echo out username,it just prints out 1

Comment: @CoderSam any suggestions, im quite stuck still, i appreciate your effort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145659/discussion-between-codersam-and-owl-man).

Comment: Good keep coding. Have fun.